# R performing linear regression within each level of a factor

Tags: r

I would like to calcute the slope and adjusted R-square between two variables (indiv_mass_log2bo and total_number_sum). My problem is that I have a huge database of 1000 lakes, where these two variables were obtained. So, I think it could do with the function `for` but I don't know how to calculate it.

Here I attach two out of 1000 lakes:

```
    lake_name        indiv_mass_log2bo  total_number_sum
   621974-134428_Bandsj�n   3,00    15,00
   621974-134428_Bandsj�n   4,00    45,00
   621974-134428_Bandsj�n   5,00    51,00
   621974-134428_Bandsj�n   6,00    98,00
   621974-134428_Bandsj�n   7,00    27,00
   623161-140769_Lerjesj�n  4,00    8,00
   623161-140769_Lerjesj�n  5,00    5,00
   623161-140769_Lerjesj�n  6,00    7,00
   623161-140769_Lerjesj�n  7,00    12,00
   623161-140769_Lerjesj�n  8,00    3,00
```

Comment: Are you looking for `lm(total_number_sum ~ indiv_mass_log2bo, data=mydata)`?

Comment: Yes! But I have to do it with each lake so as to obtain the slope and R-square

Comment: Can you run the line `dput(head(lakes, 10))` to create a reproducible example, and paste that into your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to perform one operation per lake is to create a `data.table` out of it (you'll have to install the [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) package):

```
library(data.table)
lakes.dt = data.table(lakes)
```

Then write a function that performs your linear regression and gets the desired results out, returning them as a list:

```
linreg = function(formula) {
    m = lm(formula)
    list(slope=coefficients(m)[2], adj.r2=summary(m)$adj.r.squared)
}
```

and use `by=` to perform the operation within each lake:

```
regression.results = lakes.dt[, linreg(total_number_sum ~ indiv_mass_log2bo), by=lake_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of

```
library(plyr)
sumFun <- function(x) {
  fit <- lm(total_number_sum ~ indiv_mass_log2bo, data=x)
  data.frame(slope=coef(fit)[2],adjrsq=summary(fit)$adj.r.sq)
} 
ddply(myData,"lake",sumFun)
```